# How to get href data parameter value from selected item

Tags: jquery, google-maps-markers

I have an `href` element built with the following structure:

`<a class="selected" data-marker="7" data-long="-42.398415" data-lat="36.841532" data-id="27" href="javascript:void(0);">`

There are several in the list, but I am only interested in the item that has the `selected` class.  How can I use jquery to pull the `data-marker` value from the selected link?

Comment: `var marker = $('a.selected').data('marker'); alert(marker);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dataMarker = $('a.selected').data('marker');
```

Use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to retrieve the  `a` element with a class of `selected` and [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to retrieve the value of the data attribute `marker` associated with that selector.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
var marker = parentElement.find("a.selected").prop("data-marker")
```

Comment: You should use `.attr('data-marker')` or `.data('marker`)` instead of `.prop('data-marker')` for non-DOM element properties.